# Which is better for moving from place to another in New York?

Tags: public-transport, automobiles, new-york-city

Iam Travelling for New York to work there and i will stay there , is it better for my low budget to use public transportation , or to buy a car for 1k $ and use it , is buying a car increase the a taxes  with high value or not

Comment: A big part of the question is how much it will cost you to park your car, which in turn depends on which part of the city.  (For that matter, do you mean New York City, or some other place in the state?)

Comment: @NateEldredge if this is about New York City, we also need to know where in the city.  For commuting in or between eastern Queens and eastern Brooklyn, a car is probably best, but for commuting between anywhere and any dense business district, especially those in Manhattan, public transportation is usually best.

Comment: We really, really, really need to know what part of New York.  Buffalo? Lake Placid? Brooklyn? Staten Island?  How good is the transit at the specific cross streets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buying a $1000 used car will almost certainly cost you an unknown amount in repair bills, whereas public transport is quantifiable.

Comment: Having gotten over 15 years out of a $200 car, I can attest that repair bills are not necessarily the big cost, in my car they are the 4th most expensive category.   However insurance is a definite, as well as parking, registration, tickets, smog, there are probably a dozen costs associated with cars that people just don't think about.  So the crux of your answer is rock solid.